# Is it true that when the gain of the amplifier is too high, we always need a feedback circuit to set the output node?

Tags: circuit-analysis, amplifier

Consider a simple common-source amplifier with a PMOS load. It is well-known that this circuit has a very high gain and that the output node voltage is not well-defined. For instance, changing the input bias voltage slightly can cause the output voltage to jump to one of the rails. My question is, is it possible to have an amplifier circuit that has a wide input range, a high gain, and a relatively stable output node voltage? Or is that as soon as the gain is too high, you lose control of the output?

Comment: What causes the output to remain stable? If you mean that, no matter the input, the output is fixed, it can mean that the input has no relation with the output (e.g. the output is a voltage source, non-controlled). If you mean to say that the output does follow a certain rule for a certain range of the input then what is that relation if not a feedback?

Answer (score 0):

If the amplifier has negative feedback, the **closed-loop** gain can be, in principle, as high as you want without losing control of the output.

There are other 2nd order effects that might require that you help the amplifier, with, perhaps, with a DC bias loop, but that's beyond your question.

There isn't (to the best of my knowledge) an amplifier with a predictable gain (no matter how small the gain is, eve if <1) that doesn't use feedback.

Comment: Isn't it the _open-loop_ gain that can be as high as you want without losing control of the output when using negative feedback?

Comment: @user107063 It's another way of saying it. The OP didn't say what kind of gain he's talking about. He seemed to imply in his question that if we have a low enough open-loop gain, we might not need feedback to keep the output stable. Both gains can be as high as you want (within certain limits, ofc) but the closed-loop gain implies that the output will always be stable.

Answer (score 0):

> is it possible to have an amplifier circuit that has a wide input range, a high gain, and a relatively stable output node voltage?

Output voltage range is the product of input voltage range and gain. Even if the amplifier has a rail to rail output, its output voltage cannot exceed the range between the positive and negative power supplies. So the input voltage range has an upper bound, which is: voltage between the supplies divided by gain.

So there's a little bit of a contradiction here: if you want a "wide" input range and a "high" gain (both being subjective) you will need a correspondingly "very high" supply voltage. So yeah you could use vacuum tubes with a kV supply and get lots of gain open loop.

Problems occur when semiconductor dispersion and thermal effects add an input-referred signal (like Vbe drift of 2mV/°C) which eats a significant proportion of your desired input range. Even worse, this drift can be much larger than the intended input voltage range. In this case, either feedback must be used... or in some cases, expensive matched components that compensate the dispersion and drift of the amplifying transistor with another identical one subject to the same dispersion and drift in a proper circuit.

Another way would be to use current mode: a BJT can provide a large open loop current gain. If both input and output are currents, then it can be used open loop without stability problems. However, the actual gain you will get varies a lot with temperature and semiconductor dispersion, so these current gain circuits tend to be used to make a huge but inaccurate open loop gain, then wrap feedback around it to get the desired and accurate amount of gain.